# Execute query if information is found in a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT box, name from box where 'name' !=  ''
```

but it doesn't seem to take into account the where condition into account and execute the entire query as if that condition was not there.

I essentially want to only retrieve data where there is information found in the name column.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: showing the schema would help. Plus a blank for name would not be null

Comment: Do you really have a table called `box` that contains a column called `box` or is that another potential mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT box, name from box where 'name' !=  ''
```

`'name'` is a string so the string `'name'` is `NOT EQUAL` to the string `''` which is always true.

```
SELECT box, name from box where name != ''
```

If you want where a string is not null and not empty string then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT box, name from box where COALESCE(name,'') != ''
```

and to take into account whitespace

```
SELECT box, name from box where COALESCE(TRIM(name)),'') != ''
```

Comment: Or wrap in backticks

Comment: OP probably saw an example using backticks and didnt realise they were not single quotes

Comment: quick question and thanks. I am using nodejs to execute this query. Hence, is coalesce, and trim PHP functions?

Comment: SELECT box, name from box where name != '' works perfectly

Comment: no those are mysql functions, while you are using PHP your sql statement is interpreted and executed at the database level which you tagged as mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try `name <> NULL` on your query or `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thanks i tried IS NOT NULL, but for some reason seems to have no effect

Comment: turns out you were probably right, and he did 'name' is not null

Answer (score -1):

have you tried where notnull(name,'') <> '' ?

Comment: name would still be a string if you wrap it in single quotes like that

Comment: I know you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: sure, there is a mistake, it should be without qoutes, my bad